# Kendo Tooltip template over the grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-tooltip

Im using `kendoTooltip` to display a grid data. When it hover into data, status only display `y`/`n` instead `Yes`/`No`. Any idea how make it display `Yes`/`No` by using template like `column/template`

```
  $("#grid").kendoTooltip({
    filter: "tbody td", 
    position: "bottom",
    width: 200,
    content: function(e){
      var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
      var content = ["Status      : " + dataItem.status + "<br/>",
                     "Outlet Type : " + dataItem.outletType + "<br/>",
                     "Name        : " + dataItem.name + "<br/>", 
                    ];
      return content;
    }
  }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

[FULL DEMO IN HERE](https://dojo.telerik.com/iFuJafAj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataItem is giving you exactly y and n so you can fix it like this:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(e.target.closest("tr"));
      console.log("dataItem",dataItem);
      if(dataItem.status ==="y") var fullStatus = "yes";
      if(dataItem.status ==="n") var fullStatus = "no";
      var content = ["Status            : " + fullStatus + "<br/>",
                     "Outlet Type : " + dataItem.outletType + "<br/>",
                     "Name            : " + dataItem.name + "<br/>", 
                    ];
      return content;
    }
  }).data("kendoTooltip");
});
```

Comment: it's possible to make tooltips only appear when hover in `Outlet Type`  [New Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iFuJafAj/7)